# python: pyABC with simple ODE - Traceback error <= not supported between instances str and int

Tags: python

I have a simple ODE with some unknown parameters (r, C, mu and gamma) that predicts the decay and regrowth of bacteria on a surface after being cleaned. I have experimental data for the number of bacteria at various times points (0h, 1h, 2h, 4h, 8h and 24h) after cleaning. I'm trying to use the EasyABC package to estimate the parameter distributions r, C, d and g by an Approximate Bayesian Computation Sequential Monte Carlo Simulation approach.

The ODE is defined as follows:
[image]

The experimental data looks like this:

[image]

**#Preamble**

```
from pyabc import (ABCSMC,
                   RV, Distribution,
                   MedianEpsilon,
                   LocalTransition)
from pyabc.visualization import plot_kde_2d, plot_data_callback
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tempfile
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math
db_path = ("sqlite:///" +
           os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "test.db"))
```

**#Experimental Data**

```
initial_contamination=59 #For ODE
measurement_data = np.array([19,5,5,2,9]) #To compare simulation against
s=[26,2.3,4.67,4.33,4.27] #Standard deviation used in Distance
precision=5000

measurement_times = np.array([0,1,2,4,8,24]) #Hours after cleaning
```

**#Define ODE:**

```
def ode_model(contamination,t,r,C,mu,gamma):
    Contamination = contamination;
    return(Contamination*r*(1-Contamination/C)-mu*math.exp(-gamma*t)*Contamination)

def deterministic_run(parameters):#precision,initial_contamination,r,C,mu, gamma):
    precision=5000
    tmax = 24
    time_space = np.linspace(0,tmax,precision+1)
    sim=odeint(ode_model,initial_contamination,time_space,args=(parameters["r"],parameters["C"],parameters["mu"],parameters["gamma"]))
    num_at_1=sim[int(precision*1/50.0)]
    num_at_2=sim[int(precision*2/50.0)]
    num_at_4=sim[int(precision*4/50.0)]
    num_at_8=sim[int(precision*8/50.0)]
    num_at_24=sim[int(precision*24/50.0)]
    return([num_at_1,num_at_2,num_at_4,num_at_8,num_at_24])
```

**#Define prior distribution**

```
parameter_prior = Distribution(r=RV("uniform", 0, 4),
                               C=RV("uniform", 6, 15),
                               mu=RV("uniform", 0, 4),
                               gamma=RV("uniform", 0, 4))

parameter_prior.get_parameter_names()
```

**#Define Euclidean Distance:**

```
def Distance(x,y,s):

    # computes the Euclidean distance between two lists of the same length

    if len(x) == len(y):

        return math.sqrt(sum([(((x[i]-y[i])/s[i])**2) for i in range(len(x))]))

    else:

        return 'lists not the same length'
```

**#Set up the ABC-SMC configuration**

```
abc = ABCSMC(models=deterministic_run,
             parameter_priors=parameter_prior,
             distance_function=Distance,
             population_size=50,
             transitions=LocalTransition(k_fraction=.3),
             eps=MedianEpsilon(500, median_multiplier=0.7))



abc.new(db_path, {"Contamination": measurement_data})
```

**#Run the ABC-SMC**

```
h = abc.run(minimum_epsilon=0.1, max_nr_populations=5)
```

The error I get

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

This refers to line 100 of acceptor.py

def initialize(
self,
t: int,
get_weighted_distances: Callable[[], pd.DataFrame],
distance_function: Distance,
x_0: dict):
"""
Initialize. This method is called by the ABCSMC framework initially,
and can be used to calibrate the acceptor to initial statistics.
The default is to do nothing.

```
    Parameters
    ----------

    t: int
        The timepoint to initialize the acceptor for.
    get_weighted_distances: Callable[[], pd.DataFrame]
        Returns on demand the distances for initializing the acceptor.
    distance_function: Distance
        Distance object. The acceptor should not modify it, but might
        extract some meta information.
    x_0: dict
        The observed summary statistics.
    """
    pass
```

but I cannot figure out what is wrong with it. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

**Edit: Full traceback:**

```
runfile('/Users/YYY/Downloads/Beth/Code/pyABC_Cleaning.py', wdir='/Users/YYY/Downloads/Beth/Code')
INFO:Sampler:Parallelizing the sampling on 8 cores.
INFO:History:Start <ABCSMC(id=1, start_time=2020-06-22 09:19:29.808488, end_time=None)>
INFO:ABC:t: 0, eps: 500.
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process Process-4:
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process Process-2:
Process Process-3:
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Process Process-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Process Process-6:
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
Process Process-7:
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
Process Process-8:
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 37, in work
    new_sim = simulate_one()
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 598, in simulate_one
    weight_function)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 683, in _evaluate_proposal
    x_0)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/model.py", line 213, in accept
    par=pars)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 306, in __call__
    distance_function, eps, x, x_0, t, par)
  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py", line 242, in accept_use_current_time
    accept = d <= eps(t)
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicorebase.py", line 100, in get_if_worker_healthy
    item = queue.get(True, 5)

  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 105, in get
    raise Empty

Empty


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/YYY/Downloads/Beth/Code/pyABC_Cleaning.py", line 115, in <module>
    h = abc.run(minimum_epsilon=0.1, max_nr_populations=5)

  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/smc.py", line 890, in run
    pop_size, simulate_one, max_eval)

  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/base.py", line 151, in sample_until_n_accepted
    sample = f(self, n, simulate_one, max_eval, all_accepted)

  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicore_evaluation_parallel.py", line 121, in sample_until_n_accepted
    val = get_if_worker_healthy(processes, queue)

  File "/Users/YYY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyabc/sampler/multicorebase.py", line 104, in get_if_worker_healthy
    raise ProcessError("At least one worker is dead.")

ProcessError: At least one worker is dead.
```

Comment: Can you dd the full traceback of the exception to the question?

Comment: Just edited accordingly @GPhilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from [this line](https://github.com/ICB-DCM/pyABC/blob/8cafc7bf42a309bb6ec3520091852a8d287f5396/pyabc/acceptor/acceptor.py#L242) and is caused by your distance function returning a string. You define the distance as:

```
def Distance(x,y,s):
    # computes the Euclidean distance between two lists of the same length
    if len(x) == len(y):
        return math.sqrt(sum([(((x[i]-y[i])/s[i])**2) for i in range(len(x))]))
    else:
        return 'lists not the same length'
```

so I'm guessing you end up in the `else` case, return the string and kill the workers with the error you see.
You'll have to check your `x` and `y` to find what's causing them to be of different length.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! Is there a way of being able to see what the value of each variable is as they run?